# JQuery does not show validations on the views

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong in my `edit.js.slim` file. It doesn’t show validations when required fields are empty.

**Controller**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class MerchantsController < ApplicationController
  include ControllerHelpers::StrongParameters

  def index
    @merchants = Merchant.all.load
  end

  def edit
    merchant
  end

  def update
    merchant

    respond_to do |format|
      if @merchant.update(update_params)
        format.js { redirect_to merchants_path, notice: 'Merchant was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @merchant }
      else
        format.js { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @merchant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def merchant
    @merchant ||= Merchant.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update_params
    params.require(:merchant).permit(permitted_merchant_update_attributes)
  end
end
```

**edit.js.slim** # This does not show validation error on the form even if I click 700 times

```
| $('.divTable.blueTable').bind('ajax:success', function () { $(this).hide().parent().append("
= j render 'inline_edit_form', merchant: @merchant
| "); })
```

**_inline_edit_form.html.slim**

```
= simple_form_for @merchant, id: dom_id(@merchant, 'inline_edit_form'), remote: true do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present?

  .divTable.blueTable
    .divTableHeading
      .divTableRow
        .divTableHead
          | Name
        .divTableHead
          | Description
        .divTableHead
          | Email
        .divTableHead
          | Status
        .divTableHead[colspan="2"]
          | Actions
    .divTableBody
      .divTableCell
        = f.input :name, label: false
      .divTableCell
        = f.input :description, label: false
      .divTableCell
        = f.input :email, label: false
      .divTableCell
        = f.input :status, label: false
      .divTableCell
        = f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm'
```

**update.js.slim**

```
| $('.refresh').bind('ajax:success', function () { $(this).hide().parent(); })
```

**Page Source**

[image]

So in trying to solve it, I came up with another solution inside my `edit.js.slim` and it shows validations, but when I click update button the second time, it redirects to marchant_path responding to HTML, instead of remaining on the form and showing validation offenses.

```
| $('.divTable.blueTable').replaceWith('
= j render 'inline_edit_form'
| ');
```

**Note**: I am using Rails 6.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I have in my browser's page source, the `edit.js.slim` is where the problem is. This is what I came up with:

**index.html.slim**

```
.container
  = flash_messages_for(@merchant)

  h2.title-format[id="merchant-title"]
    = t('merchant_page.table_heading.title')
  .divTable.blueTable
    .divTableHeading
      .divTableRow
        .divTableHead
          | Name
        .divTableHead
          | Description
        .divTableHead
          | Email
        .divTableHead
          | Status
        .divTableHead
          | Transaction Sum
        .divTableHead[colspan="2"]
          | Actions
    .divTableBody
      = render @merchants
```

**What I have in my Browser's Page Source**

[image]

**_inline_edit_form.html.slim**

```
= simple_form_for @merchant, remote: true do |f|
  .container
    h2.title-format
      = t('edit_page.edit_page_heading.edit')

  = f.error_notification
  = f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present?

  .divTable.blueTable
    .divTableHeading
      .divTableRow
        .divTableHead
          | Name
        .divTableHead
          | Description
        .divTableHead
          | Email
        .divTableHead
          | Status
        .divTableHead
          | Actions

    .divTableBody
      .divTableCell
        = f.input :name, label: false
      .divTableCell
        = f.input :description, label: false
      .divTableCell
        = f.input :email, label: false
      .divTableCell
        = f.input :status, label: false
      .divTableCell
        = f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm'
```

**edit.js.slim**

So this is what I came up with in my `edit.js.slim` file that made it work properly.

```
| $('.divTable.blueTable').hide().parent().prepend('
= j render 'inline_edit_form', merchant: @merchant
| ');

| $('form#edit_merchant_
= @merchant.id
| ').hide().parent().append("
= j render 'inline_edit_form', merchant: @merchant
| ");

| $("h2#merchant-title").remove(".title-format");
```